# iOS - Supporting multiple devices for one user?

Tags: ios, session, user-management

In modern mobile apps, the idea is to support multiple devices; that is assume a user has multiple iOS devices and they can use one ID to carry on using their app.

I've never done user management, user sessions before for iOS; I do recall you can't use the identifier anymore.

I don't want to bother with programming my own sign-in, register and forgot password functionality; and I feel that forcing users to "register" before using the app could end up with them dropping the "cart' and never using the app.

I'm thinking a kind of "guest" system, new users are auto-generated; although I don't know how iOS would know whether its a new user or not if its not using the device identifier any more.

Thus, my question is:

1. How do iOS apps handle user management, login and sessions where a user can easily be identified?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to crate a game you can use Game Center Account for user identification.

Comment: Okay, so this is a good start.  I think I will try to use this as a way forward; the idea being you can't proceed without Game Center sign-in?

Comment: You can store something to iCloud Keychain, and if an user using it you can get your data on other devices. But I'm really no sure about this method :)

Comment: iCloud sounds good; but the issue is I can't use iCloudKit because of device versions; it only supports the more newer devices and I would like my app to support older ones.  So I've seen apps that do indeed use iCloud key-value storage to store data, but sync with core data is not very good.

Comment: Closing this as its off topic

Comment: i found further info on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647624/how-to-manage-session-for-a-user-logged-in-from-mobile-app-in-php