# Authentication/Security regarding PHP API requests for react native

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, react-native

Im a developer with my roots in Web Development. I have always built my API's using **PHP** and now, moving forward and leaning more into App development with react native I have done the same.

I am using an SQL-database for my user data and I want to make sure that only users signed in can fetch the data from the database.

**In webdevelopement**
the way I would solve this is through a cookie storing a PHP Session and using the user_id stored within that session on the server to make the request. Therefore the API would not accept GET/POST variables, rather the user_id for which we queried for was stored on the server.

From what I have read already session API's is not something that we want to deal with when working with mobile as seen for example within this thread [How to manage session for a user logged in from mobile app in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647624/how-to-manage-session-for-a-user-logged-in-from-mobile-app-in-php)

**To summarise the question**

How do we secure our API when working with react native without having the user have to sign in over and over to reassign a SESSION on the APACHE server. I am concerned about this since if not done properly, if reversed engineered. A malicious user could start sending requests to the user with any POST/GET parameters as they please and thereby remove/add/modify user data in which it should not be able to.

Best regards. A.W

Comment: OAuth authentication.

Comment: JWT lol. Its pretty much a session in a string.

Comment: Can you explain what parts of your question are not answered by "How to manage session for a user logged in from mobile app in PHP?" (as you linked) ?

Comment: I decided to go with JWT. Thank you for the response all the 3 of you